# How to slow down opengl animation read from BVH files?

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw, glm-math, skeletal-animation

Using GLFW3, I currently made a bvh file parser which reads the file in and converts it to a human model I made in opengl. However, whenever I launch it, the movement is so fast that the animation cannot be seen in the eye. So I want to tone the animation speed a little down. Here is my render loop

```
while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        // per-frame time logic
        // --------------------
        float currentFrame = glfwGetTime();
        deltaTime = currentFrame - lastFrame;
        lastFrame = currentFrame;

        // input
        // -----
        processInput(window);

        // render
        // ------
        glClearColor(0.9f, 0.9f, 0.9f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        (Some Shader Settings)

        glm::mat4 model = glm::mat4(1.0f);

        if (moveFlag == true) {
            bvh.clearVISITED();
            bvh.setMotionPerFrame(bvh.root, 0);
        }
        if (resetMatrices == true) {
            bvh.clearVISITED();
            bvh.resetMatrices(bvh.root);
        }

        drawBones(shader, bvh.root, model);

        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }
```

The function inside the if statement `bvh.setMotionPerFrame(bvh.root, 0)` is where the animation reads in the JOINT configurations per Frame data inside the file, and sets each joint's rotation matrix and translation matrix accordingly. (`moveFlag` and `resetMatrices`are flags that are set if spacebar and r button are hit respectively)

Since reading the channel data per frame in each render loop unchangeable, I want to come up with a way that I can slower the render loop speed itself. Any suggestions?

Comment: You need a timer. Or at least a time-difference. See an example in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41273081/3871028)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add timing to your code. while you are parsing BVH MOTION like this:

```
MOTION
Frames:     20
Frame Time: 0.033333
```

you should extract the `Frame Time` value which is the time between frames in seconds. Now depending on the code architecture of yours you need to properly time your rendering. I am used to have some

```
bool _redraw=false;
```

telling whole app to redraw on next possible occasion (like timer) which is set by anything from mouse/keyboard events changing view or scene to resizing of window etc...

For time changing stuff I also usually have a function:

```
void update(double dt);
```

periodically called from app handling interpolation/simulation and stuff for `dt` time elapsed from last call. Now the `dt` can be timer interval that calls this or in case I need better accuracy I measure `dt` directly using windows `PerformanceCounter`. In case you just got endless loop you still can use:

```
Sleep(dt*1000.0);
```

which is not precise but will work.

More on animation and timing topic can be found in here and the sublinks:

- [Sprites sequence control through DeltaTime](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41920247/2521214)

Now getting back to BVH here is how my C++ update method for it looks like:

```cpp
void bvh::update() // call periodically to animate
 {
 if ((_play)&&(dt>1e-6))
  { 
  int f=frame;
  t+=tper(&t0);
  while (t>=dt)
   {
   t-=dt;
   frame++;
   if (frame>=frames)
    {
    frame=0;
    if (!_loop){ stop(); break; }
   }
  }
  if (f!=frame) setframe(frame);
 }
}
```

here some selected stuff from my BVH class:

```cpp
List<int> root;             // root bones ix
List<bvh_bone> bone;        // HIERARCHY bvh
List<double> data;          // MOTION data
int frames;                 // MOTION frames
double dt;                  // MOTION delta time [ms]
int channels;               // channels/frame
// render
bool _redraw;               // out redraw needed?
// animation
bool _loop;                 // in loop playback?
bool _play,_pause,_stop;    // out animation buttons state?
int frame;                  // actual set frame
double t,t0;                // time elapsed from start of actual frame, measurement start time
void play() { tper(&t0); t=0.0; if (!_pause) frame=0; _play=1; _pause=0; _stop=0; setframe(frame); _redraw=true; }
void stop() { tper(&t0); t=0.0;                       _play=0; _pause=0; _stop=1; frame=0; setframe(frame); _redraw=true; }
void pause(){ tper(&t0); t=0.0; if (_stop) return;    _play=_pause; _pause=!_pause; }
void setframe(int frame);   // compute bones from frame data
```

And `tper` function measures time between its subsequent calls taken from my timing lib:

```cpp
const int   performance_max=64;                 // push levels
double      performance_Tms=-1.0,               // counter period [ms]
            performance_tms=0.0,                // measured time after tend [ms]
            performance_t0[performance_max];    // measured start times [ms]
int         performance_ix=-1;                  // actual time stack index

double tper(double *t0=NULL)    // return duration [ms] between tper() calls
    {
    double t,tt;
    LARGE_INTEGER i;
    if (performance_Tms<=0.0)
        {
        for (int j=0;j<performance_max;j++) performance_t0[j]=0.0;
        QueryPerformanceFrequency(&i); performance_Tms=1000.0/double(i.QuadPart);
        }
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&i); t=double(i.QuadPart); t*=performance_Tms;
    if (t0) { tt=t-t0[0]; t0[0]=t; performance_tms=tt; return tt; }
    performance_ix++;
    if ((performance_ix>=0)&&(performance_ix<performance_max))
        {
        tt=t-performance_t0[performance_ix];
        performance_t0[performance_ix]=t;
        }
    else { t=0.0; tt=0.0; };
    performance_ix--;
    performance_tms=tt;
    return tt;
    }
```

Now in main app loop/timer just call periodicaly the `update` and if `_redraw` is true set it to false and repaint your app. Beware my `bvh::dt` was converted to [ms] !!!

Comment: Thank you Mr. Spektre! I'm the same person that asked how I can parse the bvh file to a given model in opengl. I was able to make a parser successfully during the weekends :) Thank you for the final advice!

Comment: @Peter glad to be of help and good to know you are progressing... inbetween I rewrited my old BVH class from ~6 Kb to ~18KB of C++ code adding more accurate timing (code is in here), some mesh computations and editor for dissecting single object mesh into sub-meshes if topology allows it ...